# Как отфильтровать файлы для добавления их в архив (через tarfile)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, tar, move

Хочу создать архив tar.gz средствами python с файлами текущего каталога,за некоторым исключением. Задумка такая: все выбранные файлы переносятся в каталог test-v4, а уже после происходит архивирование.

---

В каталоге test содержатся следующие файлы:

```
.
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
├── bin
│   └── transfer
│       └── .sql
├── .git
├── .test
```

Сначала сделал следующим образом:

```
#!/usr/bin env python3

import os
import sys
import tarfile

EXCLUDE_FILES = ['./.git', './bin/transfer/.sql',]

def filter_function(tarinfo):
    if tarinfo.name in EXCLUDE_FILES:
        return None
    else:
        return tarinfo

def create_archive(package, version):
    archive_name = package + "-" + version + ".tar.gz"
    with tarfile.open(archive_name, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(".", filter=filter_function)

create_archive(package=sys.argv[1], version=sys.argv[2])
```

Запускаем:

`python test.py test v4`

Получаем архив test-v4.tar.gz и смотрим листинг файлов в архиве:

```
tar -ztf test-v4.tar.gz 
./
./.test
./1
./2
./3
./bin/
./bin/transfer/
./test.py
```

Фильтр отрабатывает, казалось бы - все ок. Теперь я хочу поместить файлы в каталог. У tarfile для этого есть опция `arcname`. Добавляю параметр:

```
#!/usr/bin env python3

import os
import sys
import tarfile

EXCLUDE_FILES = ['./.git', './bin/transfer/.sql']

def filter_function(tarinfo):
    if tarinfo.name in EXCLUDE_FILES:
        return None
    else:
        return tarinfo

def create_archive(package, version):
    archive_name = package + "-" + version + ".tar.gz"
    with tarfile.open(archive_name, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(".",arcname=package+"-"+version, filter=filter_function)

create_archive(package=sys.argv[1], version=sys.argv[2])
```

Запускаем:

`python test.py test v4`

Вновь смотрим листинг файлов в архиве:

```
tar -ztf test-v4.tar.gz 
╰─ tar -ztf test-v4.tar.gz
test-v4/
test-v4/.git/
test-v4/.test
test-v4/1
test-v4/2
test-v4/3
test-v4/bin/
test-v4/bin/transfer/
test-v4/bin/transfer/.sql/
test-v4/test.py
```

Видно, что фильтр не отрабатывает при добавлении arcname.
Что я делаю не так? Подскажите,в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пути и имена в `EXCLUDE_FILES` должны соответствовать путям и именам с учётом `arcname`:

```
def filter_function(tarinfo, arcname):
    for x in EXCLUDE_FILES:
        x = x.replace('./', arcname + '/')
        if x in tarinfo.name:
            return None
    return tarinfo

with tarfile.open(archive_name, "w:gz") as tar:
    tar.add(".",arcname=package+"-"+version, filter=lambda x: filter_function(x, arcname))
```